# html tables are rendering/moving onmouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple tables, on mouse over on the row tables are floating, tables should be constant without moving. When i mouse over on the first or second table row the other tables are rendering which should not be the case. Please find the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L1b5542r/1/ .

Sample code:

```
<div id="test1" style="float: left; border: 0px solid #99ffff;">
<table cellpadding="2px" cellspacing="2px" style="border: 0px solid #ffffff; margin-right: 15px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
<tr>
<td><a id="#044b66">
<table cellpadding="2px" cellspacing="2px" style="border: 2px solid #657383; margin-bottom: 15px;" width="300px">

<tr>
<td colspan="3" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px">
<table width="300px">
<tr>
<td class="rowrowbStatus">COLUMN1</td>
<td class="rowrowbStatus">COLUMN2</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="300px">

<tr><td class="status1">row1
<img class="statusImg1" src="http://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/b_5dae6e31.png" width="15" height="15" /></td>
<td class="status2">rowb1
<img class="statusImg1" src="http://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/b_5dae6e31.png" width="15" height="15"/>
</td></tr>

<tr><td class="status1">row2
<img class="statusImg1" src="http://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/b_5dae6e31.png" width="15" height="15" /></td>
<td class="status2">rowb2
<img class="statusImg1" src="http://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/b_5dae6e31.png" width="15" height="15"/>
</td></tr>

<tr><td class="status1">row3
<img class="statusImg1" src="http://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/b_5dae6e31.png" width="15" height="15" /></td>
<td class="status2">rowb3
<img class="statusImg1" src="http://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/b_5dae6e31.png" width="15" height="15"/>
</td></tr>

<tr><td class="status1">row4
<img class="statusImg1" src="http://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/b_5dae6e31.png" width="15" height="15" /></td>
<td class="status2">rowb4
<img class="statusImg1" src="http://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/b_5dae6e31.png" width="15" height="15"/>
</td></tr>

</table></td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px">
<table width="300px">
<tr>

</tr>
</table></td></tr>

</table>
</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

How can i make tables not to be moved/rendered when i mouse over on any row in the table.

PS: You can notice this behavior if the result screen in http://jsfiddle.net/L1b5542r/1/ is dragged to view full screen and mouse over on any row of first or second table. Please suggest.Thanks.

Comment: Uh quick question: is your end goal to have each table row maintain height and width when you hover over the `tr`?

Comment: @Xenyal - No..Please see in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L1b5542r/1/  When you mouse over on first or second table rows , other tables are floating (moving) . the other tables should be constant without any movement. You can notice this output if you maximize/drag the result screen to view full in http://jsfiddle.net/L1b5542r/1/ . You can notice the 4th and 5th tables are moving if i mouse over on any row in first two tables.

Comment: I know you already accepted an answer, but are you using the same image for every mouseover? If so, why not set the image as a `background-image` instead?

Comment: @disinfor , thanks. let me try. But will that help in any way,just want to know..

Comment: @user4199704 The issue you were having was caused by the image actually taking up space. The cell needed to expand to show the image. If you set the image as a `background-image` it doesn't force a container redraw. If the image is larger than the container it's in, it will simply hide the overflow. However, you can use `background-size:contain` to make sure the full image is always shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

So below simply hid the problem by making the rows not change size when the image appeared by making the image small enough. With regards to a larger image size, you'll still get the shifting. What is happening is the use of 'float: left' is causing issues:

When table1 (top left) gets larger say it is actually moving the table below it (table 3) to the right and then shifting table 4 to some position a way bit further down and etc.

I'd recommend, if the format you want is two tables side by side, which is what I get in the fiddle, just to add some extra divs to prevent this move (or restart without using float!)

ie a 'row' div containing tables 1 & 2, another containing 3 & 4, and finally one with 5 & 6. this way you can plonk any size image in the tables and the rest will line up neatly below (though larger images than row size will still warp the row to fit the image unless you specify overflow hidden!)

Result: http://jsfiddle.net/L1b5542r/5/

---

http://jsfiddle.net/L1b5542r/3/

Edited so the image which appears on hover doesn't affect the size of the row and hence doesn't shift the rows down and force the tables out of alignment

New CSS:

```
td.status1 > img {
    display: none;
    float:right;
    height: 8px; /* define suitable height otherwise will shift*/
}
td.status1:hover > img {
    display: inline-block;
}

td.status1:hover {
 background-color: #C0C0C0;
 padding-left: 15px; /* padded to keep text central*/
 width: 85px;
}

td.status2 > img {
    display: none;
    float:right;
    height: 8px;
}
td.status2:hover > img {
    display: inline-block;
}

td.status2:hover {
 background-color: #C0C0C0;
 padding-left: 15px;
 width: 85px;
}
```